# Drools Fusion SessionPseudoClock Not working as expected

Tags: drools, kie, drools-fusion

I am trying to set `KieSession` date to same date with the date variable in my object before running the rules. I use this configuration to create my `KieSession`

```
KieSessionConfiguration configuration = KieServices.Factory.get().newKieSessionConfiguration();
configuration.setOption(ClockTypeOption.get("pseudo"));
```

Before running the rules I use `advanceTime()` to set the date of the session to desired date.

```
final SessionPseudoClock clock = kSession.getSessionClock();
clock.advanceTime(object.getDate().getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

final List<Command<?>> commands = new ArrayList<>();

commands.add(CommandFactory.newInsertElements(objects)
commands.add(CommandFactory.newInsert(object, "object"));

final ExecutionResults results = kSession.execute(CommandFactory.newBatchExecution(commands));
```

This resulted misfires in the rules that uses sliding windows. Lets say checking the objects that passed in 1 hour and I don't have any in the last hour. I only have 3 objects day before. Here is an example dataset of objects.

```
objects: [
  {
    clientId: "id",
    date: 2021-02-09T12:00:38.249Z,
    ...
  }
  {
    clientId: "id",
    date: 2021-02-09T13:00:38.249Z,
    ...
  }
  {
    clientId: "id",
    date: 2021-02-09T14:00:38.249Z,
    ...
  }
]
```

I have a rule which checks if there are more than 2 objects with the same `clientId` over 1 hour.

```
$object : Object($clientId : clientId)
List( size > 2 ) from collect ( Object( this before $object, clientId == $clientId ) over window:time(1h))
```

When I pass an object with these values. The rule above returns true but we clearly don't have any objects that has a date within last hour.

```
  { clientId: "id", date: 2021-02-10T14:00:38.249Z, ... }
```

I believe this is broken because of the new configuration as it was working previously (when I did not try to change session clock) but I want session date to be equal to object date. Anyone has ideas what is the problem here and how to fix it?

Comment: How are you incrementing the psuedo clock between calls to simulate the passage of time between events?

Comment: I understand that I have to adjust session clock for every timestamped event, and I cannot do it with newInsertElements of CommandFactory. Should I do it before or after inserting each event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Roddy of the Frozen Peas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66135292/drools-fusion-sessionpseudoclock-not-working-as-expected#comment116941828_66135292) made the remark, you need to manipulate `SessionPseudoClock` in between every insert of your events. I'd implement a new `Command`, extend `InsertElementsCommand` and `@Override` it's `execute` method:

```java
    @Override
    public Collection<FactHandle> execute(Context context) {

        KieSession kSession = ((RegistryContext) context).lookup(KieSession.class);
        List<FactHandle> handles = new ArrayList<>();

        Object workingMemory = StringUtils.isEmpty(super.getEntryPoint()) ?
                kSession :
                kSession.getEntryPoint(super.getEntryPoint());

        SessionPseudoClock clock = kSession.getSessionClock();

        super.objects.forEach(event -> {
            clock.advanceTime(((YourObject) event).getDate().getTime() - clock.getCurrentTime(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            handles.add(((EntryPoint) workingMemory).insert(event));
        });

        ...

        return handles;
    }
```

and instead of:

```java
commands.add(CommandFactory.newInsertElements(objects));
```

I'd:

```java
commands.add(new YourInsertElementsCommand(objects));
```